# Enrutar una vista modal Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Saludos! hay alguna forma de enrutar una vista modal? Imaginense que esten en el index de X recurso, dan clic en un registro, sale el modal normal, pero necesito que ese modal tenga una url reflejada en la barra de direccion tal como FB ofrece la url de ese modal, tengo pensado aprovechando que la vista show esta enrutada, hacerla modal, solo q esa vista show debe desplegarse en el index y no dentro de su propia ruta individual

En especifico lo que necesito es lo siquiente, me encuentro en la vista de empresas, al darle clic a una empresa, esta se despliega con un modal, pero necesito que al desplegarse la url cambie a la del registro mostrado en el modal, espero puedan darme ayudarme saludos!

Comment: Después de sustituir la URL, si el usuario la copia y pega en su navegador, esta abrirá la página del registro únicamente (sin modal); ¿correcto?

Comment: Saludos @Gerry la idea es que ese registro que se despliega en un modal generalmente se despliega sin una url, es decir se abre dentro de index, y la idea es compartir el enlace de ese registro, para que al darle clic al enlace compartido acceda a ese modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Manipulando_el_historial_del_navegador) para cambiar la *URL* del navegador (sin que se recargue la página).

Por ejemplo, podrías utilizar un script como el siguiente<sup>1</sup>:

```
<button id="boton">Mostrar modal</button>
<div id="mi-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade"></div>

<script>
  $("#boton").click(function() {
    $("#mi-modal").html("PRUEBA");
    $('#mi-modal').modal("show");
    history.pushState({}, '', url_recurso);
  });

  $('#mi-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    history.pushState(null, null, url_index);
  });
</script>
```

En este ejemplo, al dar clic en el botón, se abrirá un modal con el texto `"PRUEBA"`como contenido y cambiará la URL al valor establecido en `url_recurso`; y al cerrar el modal, regresarás a la URL anterior con `url_index` (considerando que `url_index` sea la URL de tu `index`).

---

La adaptación a tu caso particular depende como tengas tu código y como muestres los modales. Suponiendo que lo hagas con AJAX, entonces podrías meter la primer parte del `script` en tu `show.js.erb`:

```
$("#mi-modal").html("<%= j(render 'form') %>");
$('#mi-modal').modal("show");
history.pushState({}, '', <%= j(@url_recurso) %>);
```

Y, en lugar de un texto, podrías incluir una vista (en este ejemplo, muestro el parcial `_form.html.erb`), la cual tendría el contenido que quieres mostrar.

Es importante generar **también** la misma vista en *html*, es decir `show.html.erb`, para que los usuarios a los que se les comparta la URL puedan visitarla:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Y, finalmente, en tu controlador debes especificar los dos formatos (`js` y `html`) a los que debe responder, así como definir el valor de `@url_recurso` utilizado en tu vista `js`:

```
def show
  # ...
  @url_recurso = "url/recurso/12"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.js   # show.js.erb
  end
end
```

<sup>1</sup> *Utilizo **bootstrap** y **jQuery** para los modales y eventos.*

Comment: Saludos Gerry! Me disculpo por la demora, hasta ahora noche pude seguir trabajando en ese apartado, sucede que me muestra el modal pero no me cambia la URL, lo que hice fue agregar "enterprise" a 

history.pushState({}, '', <%= enterprise %>);

Con la intencion de que me lea la variable que contiene el id de la empresa, apoyandome del loop, pero no lo consegui, y efectivamente estoy utilizando ajax, te comparto mi codigo:

https://gist.github.com/hernandezalek/4d975949235a3cd1b6c0a2f993279f6d

Comment: @HectorHernandez ¿Qué valor contiene `enterprise`?, ¿Te muestra algún error la consola del navegador (en herramientas de desarrollador)?

Comment: Nada Gerry ni siquiera un error en la consola del navegador, e intentado ahora que me sin ajax, ya que pensadolo bien se hace dificil el llamado remoto, cuando no es un fomulario al que se llama: 

                  `<script>
                    $('#boton').click(function() {
                      history.pushState({}, '', <%= enterprise %>);
                    });

                    $('#enterprise_<%= enterprise.id %>').foundation('close'), function() {
                      history.pushState(null, null, url_index);
                    });
                  </script>`

Comment: @HectorHernandez ¿Podrías compartir (puede ser en el mismo _gist_) tu código actualizado con el comentario anterior?

Comment: Saludos Gerry! ¿Tienes algun correo de gmail? He creado un pequeño video en donde muestro mi situasion, y me gustaria convertirtelo de forma privada con lo unico que necesito agregar tu correo a los correos que seran permitidos para visualizarlo

Comment: @HectorHernandez Listo, mándalo a esta cuenta: gerry.stackoverflow@gmail.com.

Comment: Genial! Gerry! Si porque intente un Outlook y no me lo acepto, aqui te lo comparto =D https://youtu.be/i1MHO1yVbtk

Comment: @HectorHernandez El error es porque el javascript que se genera en `show.js.erb` no reconoce el texto de la variable, hay que agregar `j<%= j(@url_recurso) %>` (i.e.  para que _escape al javascript`. Ese error es esquivo pues no se muestra en ningún log. He actualizado la pregunta con esta información.

Comment: Obtengo este error

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for #<Enterprise:0x007f815618a6f8>):`

   ` 1: $('#EnterpriseModal').html('<%= j render "enterprises/single" %>').foundation('open');`

 `   2: window.history.pushState({}, '', <%= j(@url_recurso) %>);`

Busque algo por la web y tendria algo que ver con transformarlo a string

Comment: @HectorHernandez Correcto, trata de enviar un string, ahors estás poniendo el objeto `Enterprise` completo. Intenta con el nombre, i.e. `.name`.

Comment: Aparentemente funciona, agregandolo de esta forma:
`history.pushState({}, '', "<%= j(@enterprise.name) %>");`

Y automaticamente me cambia la url a esto: http://localhost:3000/San%20Martin%20de%20Sonia

Y me muestra el modal sin error, aunque me gustaria que mostrase exactamente como si estuviese en el archivo individual es decir: localhost:3000/enterprises/...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60866/discussion-between-gerry-and-hector-hernandez).

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado! Gracias a Gerry! funciona fenomenal! Dejo mi gist actualizado para futuras referencias: https://gist.github.com/hernandezalek/625da890fc30a194f711ae1b398f80e0